# Do all the levels in Nethack get generated at Start or are they generated as they are reached?

Tags: nethack

Just curious, in Nethack 343 are all the dungeon levels generated at startup, or do they only get generated by entering them?  In particular, are the Amulet and Bag of Holding fixed at start or are they akin to Schroedinger's cat?

Comment: I don't have the time at the moment to dig through the source code to find proof, but I believe that the overall structure of the dungeon (branch locations, special levels, etc) is generated at the beginning of the game, but the actual layout and content of each individual level isn't generated until you enter it. Hopefully someone else can help confirm or refute this.

Comment: The only thing akin to Schroedinger's cat is the contents of the boxes carried by Quantum Mechanics: there's special-case code that doesn't determine what the box contains until you open it.

Answer (score 6):

I have done far more experimenting with [Wizard mode](http://nethack.wikia.com/wiki/Wizard_mode) and save-scumming than I really ought to have.

I can say with reasonable certainty that the Dungeon branches, are determined at game start, because the CTRL-O command(in wizard mode) tells you where they are.

Level maps themselves are different if you first enter them after loading a copied save than the first time you entered them, so I believe that they are generated on first visit.

Comment: Translation:  The location of the Amulet of Yendor or the Sokoban branch starecase are fixed at character creation, but you can save-scum for your choice of floor-layout/reward for the last level of the Sokoban.